# Azure VM - Creating TCP inbound rules

Tags: security, azure, virtual-machine, firewall

Please, I am trying to do some that should be simple... but it is not working.

I have 03 VMs in the same subnet.

The Subnet has a security group that I created HTTP/80 inbound OK.

Now, I need to open SQL to my second VM in the same subnet.

I already try to change the security group of my VM running SQL to the same of the IIS server.

I did do my Windows firewall inbound rule too. No way.

I tried to created another rule to test if my security group was forwarding correctly, without success.

This is my SQLIN rule:

```
Priority: 2100 / Source: Any / Protocol: TCP / Source port: 1433 / Target: CIDR Block: x.x.x.x/32 (server vm azure ip (internal) / Target port: 1433 / Action: ALLOW.
```

I can access my SQL through my VPN, but I need to open to the Internet.

The another test to check if my security group is doing what I create in the rules... is... I try to open RDP through port 3390... and redirect to 3389 (because in this security group I already have 3389 published to another server...)

The rule

```
Priority: 2120 / Source: Any / Protocol: TCP / Source port: 3390 / Target: CIDR block: x.x.x.x/32 (server vm azure ip interrna) / Target port: 3389 / Action: ALLOW.
```

I did not have sucess in both rules.

Again: Subnet is associated to this security group, and BOTH VMs are associated to this sec group.

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 VMs are on the same subnet then you don't need to open up the NSG for the machines to talk to each other - you should just be able to use the windows firewall rules.  Make the SQL VM private by making sure it doesn't have a public IP, or use the NSG here.  I suspect the problem is with windows firewall from the IIS box or into the SQL box.